# Displaying mulitples of 3 and 5 under 1000 into a textbox C#

Tags: c#, wpf

We are working on the Project Euler problems and there is one part of the code I cannot get to work.

I have displayed and calculated the sum for multiples of 3 and 5 under 10, and I have calculated the sum for the same numbers under 1000 but I cannot initially display the numbers used for the calculation within a textbox or equivalent field.

Here's a link to the code.
http://pastebin.com/MZAA88UP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use loops instead of Linq:

```
    private void BtnDisplay1000_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(i);
                stringBuilder.Append(", ");
            }
        }
        TxtDisplay1000.Text = (stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: This seems a simple way, I will test out now and see if it works.

Comment: I would recommend you try out [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) when you have time, and refer to Dmitry Bychenko's answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's a good task for *Linq*:

```
int n = 1000;

var numbers = Enumerable
  .Range(1, n - 1)
  .Where(item => item % 3 == 0 || item % 5 == 0);
```

Having `numbers` as a source you can easily play with it. If you want to sum up:

```
  // 233168
  var sum = numbers.Sum();
```

If you want to print out the numbers:

```
  // 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, ..., 996, 999
  string report = string.Join(", ", numbers);
```